# Should we write a code to store token in redis if it is already given by spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-security-oauth2

In my application I have a config service that is responsible to store, get and remove values in/from redis, and security service for authentication.

I am using token based authentication, So I want to store token in redis.

Spring security provide a class RedisTokenStore.class to store token in redis which is the best solution.

But in this case two instance of redis will be created one by config-service and other by security-service.

Should I user the implementation to store token in redis or to use the config-service?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a single Redis instance then your security service should call your config service to store and retrieve tokens for authentication.